# How to config the button that invoked the command (Python Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to update the buttons when each of them are clicked. I don't want to make nine or more functions and assign each to these buttons, so I will create one function and assign it to every buttons' commands. How do I config the button that is pressed and invoked the function?

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("TTT")

white = "#f6f6f6"
black = "#050505"
grey = "#C3C3C3"

def update():
    #button.config(fg=white)
    #THIS PART IS THE PROBLEM

button11 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)
button12 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)
button13 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)

button21 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)
button22 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)
button23 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)

button31 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)
button32 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)
button33 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=update)

button11.grid(row=1, column=1)
button12.grid(row=1, column=2)
button13.grid(row=1, column=3)

button21.grid(row=2, column=1)
button22.grid(row=2, column=2)
button23.grid(row=2, column=3)

button31.grid(row=3, column=1)
button32.grid(row=3, column=2)
button33.grid(row=3, column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("TTT")

white = "#f6f6f6"
black = "#050505"
grey = "#C3C3C3"


def update(bt):
    button = eval(bt)
    button.config(fg=white)


button11 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=lambda: update("button11"))
button12 = tkinter.Button(window, text="●", width=3, height=1, font=('나눔스퀘어 bold', '20'), bg=grey, fg=grey, command=lambda: update("button12"))

button11.grid(row=3, column=1)
button12.grid(row=3, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Pass the name of the button variable as a string using

`command=lambda: update("button11")`

to the function and convert it to a variable again using `eval()`:

```
def update(bt):
    button = eval(bt)
```

This is not very professional but should work.